# How can I extend a custom LINQ operation?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of:

```
IList<MyObject> myList = new List<MyObject>();
```

and I'd like to create an exstension which take the list, and union some object. Such as

```
mylist = myList.AddCustomObjects();
```

which take myList and `UNION` it with another `List<MyObject>` generete on the fly on AddCustomObjects().

How can I do it?

Comment: You can use `Concat` or `Union` + `ToList` at the end. So the extensions exist already .

Comment: Which part do you have trouble with? Writing an extension method? Adding items to a list?

Comment: He asked to write an extended method from `List<HisObjectType>`

Comment: Um, [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)?

Comment: Use Zip:
http://jesseliberty.com/2011/06/13/the-linq-zip-operator/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an extension method, in order to achieve this. However, since the functionality you want exists for types that implement IEnumerable, like yours, I don't see the reason why you want to declare a new extension method.

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static void AddCustomObjects<T>(this List<T> source, List<T> list)
    {
        if(source!=null && list!=null)
            source.AddRange(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by following way:

```
 public class person
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }
    }
```

===================================================================

```
 public static class ListExtensions
    {
        public static List<T> AddObject<T>(this List<T> lst)
        {
            var a = default(T);
            lst.Add(a);
            return lst;
        }
    }
```

===================================================================

```
 List<person> p = new List<person>();
            var result= p.AddObject();
```

Let me know in case u need any more update!

Ashish